# BigCommerce Stencil - Create Sibling Category List on Top-Level Category Pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, bigcommerce

I've searched endlessly for a way to do this but have yet to find any help. I have recently started using a BigCommerce Stencil theme on my website and I need to create a list of subcategories. My ideal set up would be as follows:

- On each top-level category page, I would like a list of all child subcategories at the top of the page
- On the child subcategory pages, I would like a list of all sibling categories with an additional link to the top-level category

I hope this makes sense. I have yet to find a way to accomplish this and I hope someone on here will be able to help me out!

Thank you,
Karan

Comment: Hey Karan! Welcome to SO. Can you share what code you have tried so far?

Comment: HI Alyss, I have not tried any code yet as I do not know how to address the sibling categories in the theme editor for Stencil themes.

Comment: I think the only way to handle this would be to create a loop based on the parent category in the breadcrumbs. The question is, how do I address the breadcrumbs as a variable?

Comment: Still looking for help on this. I have figured out how to locate the parent category via breadcrumbs with the below code. However, I am not sure how to list out the subcategories of the parent category. 
 
This code locates the parent category in the breadcrumbs using its position. I need code that accesses and prints the subcategories.

{{#each breadcrumbs}}
            {{#if @key '===' 1}}
                {{name}}
            {{/if}}
{{/each}}

All help is appreciated! Karan